# What happenned to Quartz Composer? How can I get that functionality?

Tags: mac, xcode, apple-silicon

What, if anything, has replaced [Quartz Composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Composer)? How can I access my camera without it?

Comment: https://www.appleworld.today/2018/01/02/vuo-is-an-intriguing-alternative-to-apples-quartz-composer/

Comment: So basically they're selling what was free for years.  :(

Comment: What model is your camera? When you say 'access', do you mean live feed, upload media,....?

Comment: I have a Logitech camera for my Mac Mini.  I could have built OBS easily with Quartz Composer.  It was so powerful.  Now, even if I found a copy, it no longer runs on M1 Macs.  In other words, it was a way to handle all sorts of sound and visuals through a graph-based pipeline.  :(